# Axios random number of requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-native, axios

I need to make multiple requests with Axios but I dont know how many, the number of requests is totally random and it could be 0 or 1 or 9182379, and after they are all done I need to do something, as if now I have to update my state(array of objects).

Do you have any idea how could I do this ??

```
let oldTickets = [...this.state.playedTickets];
let length = oldTickets.length;
let newTickets = [];

for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
  let currentTicket = oldTickets[index];

  // just imported function that returns axios.get call
  checkTickets(currentTicket.ticketNumber)
    .then(data => {

      let newTicket = {
        bla: bla
      }

      newTickets.push(newTicket);
      this.setState({playedTickets: newTickets})

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    })

}
```

This is working fine but I know it's not good, so I am searching for better solution!

Comment: Can I ask why you've got to make a random amount of calls? Maybe your API needs re-engineering.

Comment: well yea maybe we will do that.... but I cant know how many "Tickets" will player play and I have to check every one of them!

Answer (score 0):

> after they are all done I need to do something

You can map the array to promises and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
Promise.all( // executes all requests in parallel
  this.state.playedTickets.map(({ ticketNumber }) => checkTickets(ticketNumber))
).then(playedTickets => { // or declare function as `async` and use `await`
  // executed only after all requests resolved
  console.log('tickets', playedTickets); 
  this.setState({ playedTickets });
}).catch(e => console.log(e)); // executed as soon as one request fails
```

**EDIT:**

> continue awaiting for all requests even if some failed, and set the state based on the results of the successful requests

To achieve this, simply catch the error before passing to `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(
  this.state.playedTickets.map(({ ticketNumber }) =>
    checkTickets(ticketNumber).catch(console.log)
  )
).then(playedTickets => {
  console.log('tickets', playedTickets);
  this.setState({ playedTickets });
});
```

Failed requests will have `undefined` as the value in the array.
If required, you can filter them out with

```
const validTickets = playedTickets.filter(ticket => ticket !== undefined)
```

Comment: yea that is good but thing is, I need to update certain object in that array in regard of that response

Comment: What do you mean? You want to continue awaiting for all requests even if some failed, and set the state based on the results of the successful requests?

Comment: yea, something like that, I want to update every object in that "playedTickets" with some respons that i get from server!

Comment: basicly i want to recreate that "playedTickets" array into new arr with this new data that I get from server, and after all that update state of my component!